# tastypie returns 401 unauthorized even when using Authorization class

Tags: django, tastypie

What i trying to do is setup a simple custom `Resource`, something as follows:

```
MailResource(Resource):
    to = fields.CharField(attribute='To')
    subject = fields.CharField(attribute='Subject')
    message = fields.CharField(attribute='Message')

    class Meta:
        resource_name = 'mail'
        allowed_methods = ['post']
        authorization = Authorization()

        def detail_uri_kwargs(self, bundle_or_obj):
            kwargs = {}
            if isinstance(bundle_or_obj, Bundle):
                kwargs['pk'] = bundle_or_obj.obj.uuid
            else:
                kwargs['pk'] = bundle_or_obj.uuid
            return kwargs

        def obj_create(self, bundle, request=None, **kwargs):
            print bundle.obj
            print request
            print kwargs
            # Create the object
            return bundle
```

But when i make a test post request using curl, i always get 401 UNAUTHORIZED error. why so ? Isn't `Authorization()` class is meant to return true for `is_authorized` method. The [documentation](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/authorization.html) says `Authorization()` is :

> The no-op authorization option, no permissions checks are performed.

then why is it failing ?

#### Update:

I also tried a custom authorization class which always return `True` in the `is_authorized` method no matter what, but it still raises 401 UNAUTHORIZED error. Any Clues?

Comment: What kind of authentication do you use?

Comment: Also only allowed method in your resource is 'post', that means you can't make GET on this resource.

Comment: i am not using Authentication at all, even if i use Authentication the result is still the same.

Comment: and yeah i only want to allow post method for this resource and am making post request to check it.

Comment: You might want to enable GET as well and see what result you get. How does the curl call that gives you the 401 look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been facing the same issue. Looks like SessionAuthentication is not supposed to work with HTTP POST.

Have explained more here

[Does SessionAuthentication work in Tastypie for HTTP POST?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15388694/does-sessionauthentication-work-in-tastypie-for-http-post/15390938#15390938)

Comment: I've gotten POST to work with SessionAuthentication, but you need to pass the csfr token as described in the docs.

Comment: I've added an answer with an example to the question you linked to. Not sure if SessionAuthentication works with curl though.

Comment: I guess you could manually get the token and include it in your curl call.