# request.user is Anonymous even after login in Angularjs , django-tastypie

Tags: django, angularjs, tastypie

I'm having big trouble with login in Tastypie and Django.

Through AngularJSs I send my login request like below :

```
var request = $http({
                    method: "post",
                    url: API_URL + "api/v1/global/login/",
                    data: {'user':$scope.login_user, 'password':$scope.password}


                });
```

Then inside LoginResource in api.py I added separate function (different types of users in my project) :

```
def login(self, request, **kwargs):
        self.method_check(request, allowed=['post'])
        data = self.deserialize(request, request.body, format=request.META.get('CONTENT_TYPE', 'application/json'))
        user = data.get('user', '')
        password = data.get('password', '')
        user = authenticate(username=user, password=password)
        if user.is_active:
           login(request, user)
           print(request.user.is_authenticated(), request.user.id, request.session.session_key)

                return self.create_response(request, {
                    'success': True,
                })
```

The request.user.is_authenticated() shows *True* value.

I have MessageResource in my `api.py` :

```
class MessagesResource(ModelResource):
    login_user = fields.ForeignKey(UserResource, 'login_user', null=True, full=True)
    from_person = fields.ForeignKey(UserResource, 'from_person', null=True, full=True)
    to_person = fields.ForeignKey(UserResource, 'to_person', null=True, full=True)
    create_user = fields.ForeignKey(UserResource, 'create_user', null=True, full=True)
    update_user = fields.ForeignKey(UserResource, 'update_user', null=True, full=True)
    class Meta:
        allowed_methods = ['get','post','delete','put','patch']
        queryset = Messages.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'messages'
        authorization = Authorization()
        authentication = Authentication()
        always_return_data = True
        filtering = { 
            'from_person':ALL,
            'to_person':ALL_WITH_RELATIONS,
            'status':ALL
                    }

    def get_object_list(self, request):
        print('request.user.id=',request.user.id)
        return super(MessagesResource, self).get_object_list(request).filter(to_person__id=request.user.id)
```

Here inside `get_object_list request.user.id` is *None*. What am i doing wrong?

**Note**: After login in login controller I redirected to '`Dashboard.html`'.. Does this redirect has any effect in this request ?

**EDIT**: This is my login resource

```
class GlobalLoginResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = User.objects.all()
        allowed_methods = ['get','post']
        resource_name = 'global'
        authorization = DjangoAuthorization()
        excludes = ['password']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using standard `Authentication` which means "no authentication at all", the method `is_authenticated` doesn't check or assign user to request. So user `bundle.request.user` will be anonymous in this particular resource. I see you have signed request up in login resource. So guessing you will have to use `SessionAuthenctication` or generate api_key in login. And use that in `MessageResource` as `ApiKeyAuthentication` or other.

You should see how `is_authenticated` works for each authentication method:
[Authentication](https://github.com/toastdriven/django-tastypie/blob/master/tastypie/authentication.py#L47)
[BasicAuthentication](https://github.com/toastdriven/django-tastypie/blob/master/tastypie/authentication.py#L104)
[ApiKeyAuthentication](https://github.com/toastdriven/django-tastypie/blob/master/tastypie/authentication.py#L176)
[SessionAuthentication](https://github.com/toastdriven/django-tastypie/blob/master/tastypie/authentication.py#L244)

**Note response**: Redirect is not related here.

Comment: So after adding Session authentication It blocks the call to messages api showing GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/messages/ 401 (UNAUTHORIZED) .. But i logged in already and session exists on browser..

Comment: Please look at the EDIT.

Comment: I guess you have to customize your AngularJS request to handle Django session properly. But this is an other question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15388694/does-sessionauthentication-work-in-tastypie-for-http-post